# how to convert MapPartitionsRDD to a dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I have a MapPartitionsRDD returned from:

```
from pyspark.mllib.feature import Normalizer
normalizer = Normalizer()
rating = normalizer.transform(ratingRDD)
print(rating)

> MapPartitionsRDD[239] at mapPartitions at PythonMLLibAPI.scala:1522
```

How can I convert this to a dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
rating.map(lambda x: (x, )).toDF()
```

Comment: This method is unavailable to MapPartitionsRDD or even RDD type.